# Node.Js - Impossible to use lldb on m1

Tags: node.js, apple-m1, lldb, coredump

I'm trying to make a post-mortem debugging session for a Node.Js process.

Here is my *modus operandi*:

- Run `ulimit -c unlimited` command
- Run the command: `node --abort-on-uncaught-exception crash.js`
- where `crash.js` is:

```
throw new Error('BOOM');
```

Then the console outputs:

```
➜  /cores arch -arm64 lldb node -c core.6511
(lldb) target create "node" --core "core.6511"
Core file '/cores/core.6511' (arm64) was loaded.

(lldb) bt
* thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x000000010553e3e4 node`v8::base::OS::Abort() + 24
(lldb)
```

I have only one frame instead of a bunch of them.

I'm working on a:

- MacBook air (m1, 2020)
- OS Monterey - 12.6

Comment: Most likely the Abort function is doing something clever in setting up its stack (since it knows that nothing else is going to happen after it's execution) and so it doesn't look like a frame type that lldb knows how to unwind from.  If you want to follow up on this, it's probably best to file a bug either with Apple's bug tracker or the llvm.org bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JimIngham 

I was influenced by a tutorial https://blog.cjihrig.com/postmortem_debugging where `lldb` display more frame than in my case. 

>  If you want to follow up on this, it's probably best to file a bug either with Apple's bug tracker or the llvm.org bug tracker

Really good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I put my hands on an intel mac this morning, and it worked as expected; I see all the native Node.js frames ^^

As Jim suggested, I'll open an issue on Apple's bug tracker. I'll post updates here.